# Add hours to project

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up an time tracker in google-sheet to track my time in certain projects. Now my knowledge is limited from this, but I am gonna try to explain. I have created dropdowns that uses the projects from a different sheet. It allows me to select the project I have been working on. What I want is that if I fill in a field next to it with the time ammount that it will be added to a global project time.

So for instance, i worked 120 minutes on project x, and I fill that in, i want it to be added to the number of the project on top (so a global of say: 5 hours + 120 minutes will be then 7 hours). Right now, I do the selecting manually, but is there a way to have google docs calculate that if i select project x, it has to add the time to a certain project?

[image]

As you see, if I enter a time on project x, after the select, i want it to be added to the total on the side. Is this possible with some kind of formula?

Comment: Look at the [query() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Comment: @Karl_S actually no, that doesnt work ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(C7:C60;Variabelen!A3;D7:D60)
```

At this point I experimented with the SUMIF function, and I actually got what I wanted. Basically what it does is it checks in the cells C7:C60 if there is a variable that matches A3 from the variabelen sheet. If so, it adds the number of the cell behind it (D7 till D60) to the cell provided, which works amazingly well.